# Scrolling in a itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, scrollviewer

I have an `ItemsControl` template which contains another `ItemsControl` and its template contains a `DataGrid`.

I want to be able to scroll through the first `ItemsControl`, therefore I used the `ScrollViewer`.

The issue is that when the mouse is over any of the 2 `ItemsControl` scrolling works, but when the mouse is over the `DataGrid` it doesn't.

Would you know how I can fix this ?

```
<TabItem Header="Summary">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CheckResultViewModels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding CheckResults.Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    <Run>Warnings</Run>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding CheckResults}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Margin="5">
                                            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                                      AutoGeneratingColumn="DetailsDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
                                                      CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                                      IsReadOnly="True"
                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorData}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: That's because DataGrid ScrollViewer eats up scroll event to handle it's scrolling. Don't you want DataGrid to scroll?

Comment: I don't think it would need to, since it has infinite vertical space provided by the outer ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DataGrid have ScrollViewer in it's default template. So, when mouse is over DataGrid, ***scroll event is eaten up by dataGrid's ScrollViewer and thus doesn't bubbles up to parent ScrollViewer***.

In case you want outer ScrollViewer to scroll you can hook tunnelling **`PreviewMouseWheel`** event and scroll manually:

**XAML**:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CheckResultViewModels}">
        ...........
```

**Code behind**:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, 
                                            MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
}
```